# in Boostrap 5, carousel moves full page instead of just his images

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

i am learning bootstrap 5, i have tried to create simple carousel by following official documentation of Bootstrap 5 [Bootstrap 5 Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/). but when i simply copied their code and used in my template i got unexpected error.my carousel moving full page content instead of his images.  Content after Carousel Div also moves when Carousel moves and when i put more div or section on page full page moves along Carousel move. here is my code [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi)

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="icons/fontawesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" />
  
  <style>
    /*** Slider Box ***/
    
    .sliderbox {
      margin-left: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
      background-color: darkkhaki;
      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption {
      bottom: 20%;
      padding-right: 80%;
      width: 25%;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .slider-image-heading {
      font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: xx-large;
      color: white;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
    }
    
    .slider-image-text {
      margin-top: 40px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    
    .slider-image-btn {
      background-color: #56e0cd;
    }
    
    .slider-image-btn:hover {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      border-color: white;
    }
    
    .carousel-control-prev-icon {
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .getrugdiv {
      background-color: #215f6a;
      width: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/austin-fireworks.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/taj-mahal_copy.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/ibiza.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid getrugdiv">
    <h1> Boot Your Trip Now</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

After a lot of trial and error, I found out that after deleting `margin: 0;` from `.carousel-inner .carousel-item {...}` the carousel started working (i.e. white space doesn't appear every time the slide is changed).

So, change this...

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

...into this.

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="icons/fontawesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" />

  <style>
    /*** Slider Box ***/
    
    .sliderbox {
      margin-left: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
      background-color: darkkhaki;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption {
      bottom: 20%;
      padding-right: 80%;
      width: 25%;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    .slider-image-heading {
      font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size: xx-large;
      color: white;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
    }
    
    .slider-image-text {
      margin-top: 40px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
    
    .slider-image-btn {
      background-color: #56e0cd;
    }
    
    .slider-image-btn:hover {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      border-color: white;
    }
    
    .carousel-control-prev-icon {
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .getrugdiv {
      background-color: #215f6a;
      width: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/austin-fireworks.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/taj-mahal_copy.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/ibiza.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid getrugdiv">
    <h1> Boot Your Trip Now</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks yes its working fine . thanks alot. do you think my question was hard to understand ? why someone gave me -1 ?